# WSO2-IS: User Stores deletes after any changes in it

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I'm using WSO2-IS version 5.8.0. I have successfully established ReadOnly connection with my Active Directory LDAP Server, but faced another problem:

I have configured LDAP for users like in example below:

```
Connection URL: ldaps://your.domain.com:686
Connection Name: CN=John Dee,OU=Users,DC=your,DC=domain,DC=com
Connection Password: mygoodpassword
User Search Base: OU=Users
Username Attribute: sAMAccountName
User Search Filter: (&(objectClass=user)(sAMAccountName=?))
User List Filter: (objectClass=person)
```

Everything works fine, users were added and I was able to login to my services using SSO.

The problem has appeared when I have tried to add Roles(Groups from AD):

Below a parameters which I used for AD groups adding:

```
Group Search Base: OU=Groups
Group Name Attribute: sAMAccountName
Group Search Filter: (&(objectClass=group)(sAMAccountName=?))
Group List Filter: (objectClass=group)
Membership attribute: member
```

Afterwards I have clicked on "Update" button, and User Store has disappeared, but .xml file on the server still exists.

I tried to configure ReadOnly LDAP using .xml on the server, but after any edits in the User Store from UI - the same issue appears.

Comment: The user store file redeploys when you do any changes. You should be seeing logs related to this in the server. After a few seconds, you should be able to see the redeployed user store in the UI

Comment: Thank your for your comment. I forgot to mention, that in the logs I found the following error message: 
`TID: [-1234] [] [2019-10-04 12:01:32,512]  INFO {org.apache.axis2.deployment.DeploymentEngine} -  org.apache.axis2.deployment.DeploymentException: `
The deployment of Example.xml is not valid. Of course - the error message if self-explained, but every operation was done only using UI. Is there field verification problem?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution for the problem. By unknown reason when I initially installed all parameters in UI, but there was a problem in XML file:

```
/usr/lib64/wso2/wso2is/5.8.0/repository/deployment/server/userstores/Example.xml:
```

Initial value:

```
<Property name="GroupNameSearchFilter">(&(objectClass=group)(sAMAccountName=?))</Property>
```

After my changes:

```
<Property name="GroupNameSearchFilter">(&amp;(objectClass=group)(sAMAccountName=?))</Property>
```

I have restarted wso2 service and now everything work fine. 
However, it seems the problem in UI fields verification, I don't know why wso2 UI didn't validate fields in User Stores.